# Sonar Pitest Plugin

Tags: maven-3, sonarqube, mutation-testing, pitest

I want to integrate some [mutation testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutation_testing) to ensure the quality of my junit tests. I want to have the results in the [sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/) dashboard of my project.

The [sonar pitest plugin](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-pitest) seems to do what I want, but there are some issues with maven 3 and it is still under development.

Has anyone ever tried this plugin ?
Are there others alternatives ?

Comment: I've tried the plugin with some small projects. You can still use it with Maven 2. Why don't you give it a try?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am fairly sure there are no other mutation testing plugins for sonar.

I've not actually tried the pit sonar plugin myself, but I understand the issue with maven 3 can be worked around

see

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/pitusers/bkDD13iBtHU

The PIT maven plugin itself is quite mature and is being used successfully in production. If you encounter issues with the sonar plugin you could just publish the maven reports from your CI server.

Please do feedback any issues you hit - I'm sure Alexandre will be kean to fix them.

Comment: Thanks henry, it seems that you knows well pit :) Thanks for the link providing the workaround. I will try it.